# How to import then build multiples local jars (~100) into a maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-boot, talend

First of all, sorry if my question seems to be duplicated but I have thoroughly search during hours and hours a solution without any success...

This is my current context :

1. I have developped a huge talend job which uses many others jobs
2. I have built my talend job as a standalone jar. That resulted in a zip file containing a lot of others jars (around 100). All of those jars are needed for my talend job to work. Those are secondary jobs or libraries, etc.
3. Then I have made a spring-boot java application (using maven...) that can run my talend job among others things.
4. In order to do that, I had to import every jars into my project => i.e build path. Those 100+ jars are all visible inside the "referenced libraries" folder.
5. When I run my app through Eclipse, everything is working well but now what I need is to build this app as a jar, or something I can run on another machine/server.

I don't know anything about maven, but if I understand well, I need to use the command maven-install in order to build my project... The problem is the command throw me errors because it doesn't find all my libraries.

I found many solutions that says to create a local repository, to use maven-install for each jar, or maven-deploy for each jar, then add dependencies into my pom file for each jar...

As you could understand, that's not a good solution for me and my 100+ jars...

I heard about nexus or something like that, but I am the only one person working on this project and this solution seems to be interresting when a whole team is working on the same project.

So, if any of you knows how I can manage that, I would be very grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: How many of these 100+ jars are built by yourself and how many are third-party jars?

Comment: They all come from the built of my talend job ! When I build it I get a zip file with all those jars

Comment: To work properly with Maven, all these jars have to get a groupId, artifactId and version and go either to your local repository or a Nexus/Artifactory. If you _build_ the jars with Maven, Maven will take care of putting the jars in the right place. If you generate the jars with some other tool, it might be more difficult. If do not know about talend, but I would look into the docs if you can create the jars in a Maven compatible way. If this is not possible, you need to install/deploy these jars yourself. If you have 100+ I would write scripts.

Comment: it seems that i can't create the jars in a Maven compatible way without the enterprise version of talend. i.e with the free open studio version... 

Then the script seems to be the only one solution remaining but I don't know how i could manage that... Some researches are required atm.

Thanks